# Drop targets in nested control

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

In a win form I have placed a panel control (the parent), on DragDrop event I am creating another panel inside this parent (the child). Now when I drag any thing on to the child control the event is fired only on the parent panel.

How do I pass on the event to the child control?

Comment: Can a parent have multiple panels ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. In my case the parent panel can have any number of child panels created depending on the number of time an object was dragged on to it.

Comment: You answered my question ... Can a child be a parent as well ? that is to contain children(Panels)

Comment: No. The child will have other user controls placed on it. The first panel acts as a stage, on dragging an object a child is created to act as a group and then the final layer of user control has to be placed on the child panel.

Comment: So why do you want the child to know about the drag and drop event ?

Comment: Because I must be able to drag more than one control to the created child panel. Hence it important to know the drop location. If a control is dropped on the parent a child should be created else it should be added to an existing child panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue here. The DragEnter event on the parent was consuming the DragEffect irrespective of type of object being dropped. Changing the method to consume only specific objects allowed the event to propagate. Got the hint from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.drop%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).